# Как убрать резкое перескакивание плавающего header'a?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем доброго времени суток, написал скрипт для плавающего header'a
Проблема в том, что когда он становится "Плавающим" он резко перескакивает, когда становится обратно статическим, то опять же вся происходит резко, как это исправить?

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
  header = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
  var headerStyle = header[0].style;
  if (event.pageY >= 100) {
    headerStyle.position = 'fixed';
    headerStyle.top = '0';
    headerStyle.left = '0';
    headerStyle.width = '100%';
  } else {
    headerStyle.position = 'static';
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
```

Пробовал задать `transition: 1s;` header'у, но это не помогает.

Comment: Добавьте padding-top для родителя взяв высоту header

Answer (score 0):

Изменение позиционирования с `fixed` на `static` не анимируется. А так как у вас оно происходит на высоте 100px - получается скачок.
Лучше делать шапку изначально фиксированной, а `body` задавать `padding-top` равный высоте шапки(чтобы контент не накрывала).

```js
function headerSpace(){
  var headerHeight = document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;
  document.body.style.paddingTop = headerHeight + 'px';
}
headerSpace();
window.onresize = headerSpace();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
ol{
  list-style-position:inside;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<ol>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
  <li>А тут много контента</li>
</ol>
```